# Why would Gollum like climbing trees in fair weather?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97129/how-did-gollum-know-about-the-rescue-party-from-dol-guldur), asked yesterday, put a somewhat related question into my mind. As quoted in that question:

> ‘In the days of fair weather we led Gollum through the woods; and there was a high tree standing alone far from the others which he liked to climb. Often we let him mount up to the highest branches, until he felt the free wind; but we set a guard at the tree’s foot. One day he refused to come down, and the guards had no mind to climb after him: he had learned the trick of clinging to boughs with his feet as well as with his hands; so they sat by the tree far into the night.’

Now, it is quite well-established that Gollum’s long and gradual transformation and eventual retreat into the pits of Moria had entailed a deep and unwavering fear and hatred of the Moon and—especially—the Sun (even the stars he is suspicious of). Even in the parts of *The Two Towers* and *Return of the King* where his Gollum persona is less prominent and his long-forgotten Sméagol persona comes to the fore, he mistrusts the ‘Yellow Face’ and always prefers to lie in hiding during the day and on clear, moonlit nights; so this phobia of celestial bodies is not purely a Gollum thing that goes away when Gollum goes away.

And yet, if we are to trust Legolas, when he was held captive by the Elves in Mirkwood—a place quite sheltered from sunshine and one where he ought to be quite happy, apart from the presence of elves—he apparently enjoyed something so out of character as

- climbing a tree that stood alone, exposed, and unprotected,
- climbing up so high that he could feel “the free wind” (i.e., presumably so high that he was above the forest itself and exposed to the sky),
- doing all this “in the days of fair weather”, when the Sun must be assumed to be out.

How can this be?

Comment: Very good question. Very unlike Gollum to do these things. But perhaps he intended to make himself visible to the orc spies and perhaps even to bird-spies of Sauron, which would lead to his rescue.

Comment: Perhaps his fear and hatred of the Elves and all things Elven overrode his fear of the sun?

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Except the description is that he _liked_ to climb that tree. And why, if it were just to get away from the elves, would he choose a lone tree that stood far away from the other trees? Why not choose one in a denser area and then just climb away through the treetops or higher branches? Why climb _all the way_ up, rather than just far enough to be out of the elves’ reach?

Comment: @Maksim Could be. It's a theory that makes sense, at least, though he wasn't too keen on going back into the tender care of Sauron’s servants either. Given an ultimatum between being caught by elves and being caught by Sauron(’s servants), I wonder which he'd choose.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet no, Legolas tells us there was a tree he liked to climb. We do not have Gollums version to back it up. He would also want to get as far away as possible from the elves so the higher the better. As my answer to the other question States, the "rescue" scenario is possibly an error on Legolas' part

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Yes, I quite agree that there was no ‘rescue’. But Legolas would also have no reason to say that there was a tree Gollum liked to climb if that weren't true.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gollum climbing the tree isn't in doubt. Gollum "liking" to is. There is a tree he liked to climb could indicate there was a consistent tree he climbed, not specifically that he enjoyed it

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Surely the two come to more or less the same here. Why would he choose _that particular tree_ to climb, rather than one in a denser area that would afford protection from the Sun and a possible means of escape, if he didn't for whatever reason like it? Maksim’s theory (to be visible to spies who might help him get away) is the only one I can see that makes sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet only if you accept he wished to be "rescued" by the orcs. I don't.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Perhaps not orcs in particular, but I would imagine he probably would quite like to be rescued (though I doubt anyone else than the orcs would be interested). He may have considered orcs to be easier to give the slip than elves—he hated orcs, but at least he _understood_ them, unlike elves—so I don't think he would have balked at the idea of being ‘rescued’ by orcs, as long as it meant getting away from the elves.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Sauron actually released Gollum from Mordor, and the orcs allowed him to pass through. Gollum was playing some role in Sauron's plans, and I guess orcs considered him to be just another of Sauron's servants. In the end, Gollum was indeed rescued by orcs and allowed to go free.

Comment: @Maksim But Gollum didn't know that he was allowed to go—he thought his own sneakiness had got the better of the orcs and that he'd escaped.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - he was allowed to have these outdoor "sessions" repeatedly, and I think he figured out that if he made himself more visible to any potential spies, he'd get a rescue. But yeah, that's just my theory. The other question you linked to quotes that "Now Sauron learning of the capture of Gollum by the chiefs of his enemies was in great haste and fear." So, even if there wasn't a direct sequence of Gollum being spotted by the spies and rescued, Sauron did order orcs to attack Elves in Mirkwood (something which I'm sure they wouldn't do of their own accord)... [to be cont.]

Comment: and Gollum seemed to figure out that if he sits high up in the tree, out of the Elves' reach, there will come an attack from orcs, which will give him a chance to escape.

Comment: My two cents: Gollum did not pick the remote tree he was allowed to climb. Knowing Gollum would immediately scamper away through the tree tops, his captors would have chosen an isolated tree or none at all. I would think Gollum *liked* the exercise and the illusion of freedom. I think he was resigned to climb *that* tree because it was the only tree he was allowed to climb.

Comment: Maybe the Elves treated him worse than they are saying and made this story up!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my non canon two cents worth of an opinion: Gollum did not pick the remote tree that he was allowed to climb. Knowing Gollum would immediately scamper away through the treetops, his captors would have chosen an isolated tree or none at all. I would think Gollum *liked* the exercise and the illusion of freedom, but I think he was resigned to climb *that* tree because it was the only tree he was allowed to climb in order to get the exercise and illusion of freedom.

Comment: Non-canon, but good speculation and good point. Worth a +1, at least. :-)

Comment: +1 great point, hadn't considered that the elves would see climbing tree in bunched area would be risky

Comment: Accepting this, because it looks like it’s as much of an answer as we’re likely to get.

Answer (score 1):

Gollum had just been tortured at length by Sauron in a deep, dark pit under Mordor. I guess that for a while that changed his attitude to the open air and sunlight. He must have been severely traumatised by his recent experiences and thus acting out of character.

Comment: He was released from Mordor a whole year before this happened, and immediately after escaping from Mirkwood, he goes back to live in Moria, where he doesn’t leave until the Fellowship pass through. I’d say it’s quite unlikely that his trauma caused such a very fundamental change in his personality to last for a whole year (including through his interrogation at the hands of Gandalf and Aragorn), only for it to then vanish immediately afterwards.

Comment: He doesn't go to live in Moria, he was attempting to pass through to the West in search of 'Baggins', but couldn't figure out how to open the West gate doors.  (IIRC Tolkien says in "Unfinished Tales" that he just wasn't strong enough to push them open.)  One might theorize that after his 'rescue' by the Orcs, they took him to Moria to elude Elvish pursuit, and he escaped them along the way.

Comment: @jamesqf He doesn't go there in order to live there, no; but he does stay there, so he goes back to living there (previous comment should have had a participle instead of an infinitive, that's true).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: But staying is not entirely his choice.  He can't get out the west door (which he badly wants to do in order to get to 'Baggins'), going back east would take him away from his goal, and he'd have to go through all those Orcs and risk being recaptured.  So he's caught between a rock and a hard place, unable to decide what to do, when along come our heros.  Who were themselves only driven to take this path because the mountain pass was closed...